# How to switch element's Flow Direction one each in wp 8.1?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1, json.net

Based on a design I've got for my app, I need to change FlowDirection of my ListView items on each item, So first item has LTR & the second one has RTL and so on.

Before because I used to scrape data right in app, So I add a parameter to list. But now I'm using a JSON API & populating it with `Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.PopulateObject`, So I don't have any loop to add the parameter.

How could I do this simply?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different options based on your scenario , one of the easiest one to implement can be:

Use an ObservableCollection for your item source, and subscribe the CollectionChanged event of it, as it's name suggests, it fires whenever the collection has been modified, in your scenario, we will use it to detect the Addition changes to update the flow direction per item.
Simply you can first get the item index and finally divide it by two and check if it's dividable to apply to flow direction desired change.